# Float Menu like on TheVerge reviews posts Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have code like this:

```
$(".jumper").on("click", function( e ) {

e.preventDefault();

$("body, html").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
}, 600);

});
```

This is how it's going to work http://jsfiddle.net/ZVdRt/291/

How to make a menu that change backgorund of pilip or Ploop when they rich specific level?

Sorry for my language;) Here is example of TheVerge float menu in post http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/14/5608222/samsung-galaxy-s5-review

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want is to change the background of the link once it reaches the destination (end of scroll). This can be done by using the *complete* function of *animate*:

```
$(".jumper").on("click", function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // reset background for all jumpers, and save current one
    $(".jumper").css("background","");
    obj = this;

    $("body, html").animate(
        { 
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
        }, 
        600, 
        function() {
            // change background for current jumper when the animation is completed
            $(obj).css("background","black");
        });

});
```

I hope this is what you meant. You can see it working on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVdRt/298/ (I also added a z-index to your #menu css so the keywords wouldn't overlap it.)

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to add/remove class for the menu links instead of doing it manually as I did in that example.